# Generalizing lambda or expression

Tags: lambda-calculus

I want to generalize

$$
\underline{or} = \lambda xy. (x \to \underline{true} | y)
$$

to $\lambda AB. (A \to (\underline{true} \to ...) | B \to ...)$.

Here's my try:

Cases:

- If A:

  - If B: $\underline{true} \to Axy \to x$
  - If $\underline{not}$ B: $\underline{true} \to Axy \to x$
- If $\underline{not}$ A:

  - If B: $Bxy \to x$
  - If $\underline{not}$ B: $Bxy \to y$

So

$$
\underline{or}
= \lambda ABxy. (A \to (\underline{true} \to x|x) | (B \to x|y))
= \lambda ABxy. (A \to x | (B \to x|y))
= \lambda ABxy. Ax(Bxy)
$$

I forgot to mention that $A,B$ are boolean.

Are the steps seem reasonable? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Please explain your notation, what does $\to$ and $|$ mean?

Comment: hi @Couchy E -> E1 | E2 means if E then E1 else E2

Comment: I don't see what you're trying to do